# Can I define unique basis functions in GAMs?

Tags: generalized-additive-model, smoothing, mgcv

I am modelling a process evolving over time using GAMs.  There is some theory that says that the time evolution should look like a particular function, so I would like to smooth the time component using this function as a basis (instead of a b-spline or something).

Is there a way I can specify a basis function in gam?  The basis function I want to use looks something like $c_1(e^{c_2t} − e^{c_3t})$ .